# Momentjs get list of timezones where current time is 10:00 AM

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to run a scheduler which needs to select all those users whose morning time is 10:00 AM in their timezone GMT (+5.5, +1, +6, -4 etc.). I got user's timezones in my database and my scheduler will send email to the user at 10 AM of their location.

I need to get all GMT timezones (+5.5, +1, +6, -4 etc.) every half an hour, where local time is 10:00 AM, so I can query database for users only with specific timezones.

Comment: Ok, that was easy:

moment.tz.names().filter(z => moment().tz(z).hours() >= 10)